# Adding subview in `touchesBegan:withEvent` has delay before being drawn

Tags: ios, uiview

This is the container view:

```
@implementation

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.tapView removeFromSuperview];
    self.tapView = nil;
    self.tapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 10.0f, 10.0f)];
    self.tapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:self.tapView]; // Takes too much time before view shows up on screen
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.tapView removeFromSuperview];
    self.tapView = nil;
}

@end
```

I'm looking to understand why there is a delay between the moment the `tapView` is added as a subview and being drawn on screen. It's only a few milliseconds but it's noticeable.

The best example of the performance I am looking to achieve is when tapping on the native keyboard. Tapping on a key shows up a new view (or is it?) instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
The container view was inside a scroll view with 'Delays Content Touches' enabled.